# virtualbox cloud-init smbios equivalent

Tags: virtualbox

Over at the cloud-init [core tutorials](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/qemu.html#launch-a-virtual-machine-with-our-user-data) there is a sample command which instructs cloud-init to fetch the cloud-init related data from http. The command is pasted below for convenience:

```
qemu-system-x86_64                                            \
    -net nic                                                    \
    -net user                                                   \
    -machine accel=kvm:tcg                                      \
    -cpu host                                                   \
    -m 512                                                      \
    -nographic                                                  \
    -hda jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img                        \
    -smbios type=1,serial=ds='nocloud;s=http://10.0.2.2:8000/'
```

I am referring to the line which goes like `-smbios type=1,serial=ds='nocloud;s=http://10.0.2.2:8000/'`

Is there a Virtualbox equivalent way to achieve this?